# Iteration through the items of a JSON and get the latest records

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have A JSON string and Id like to have 1 or 2 latest records depends on the timestamp of my JSON.

**Example look like this**

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1612283061106,
        "user": "email1",
        "ipAddress": "IP1",
        "resourceType": "Login",
        "resourceName": "Name1"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1612282839939,
        "user": "email1",
        "ipAddress": "Ip3",
        "resourceType": "Login",
        "resourceName": "name1"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1612279167153,
        "user": "email2",
        "ipAddress": "Ip2",
        "resourceType": "Login",
        "resourceName": "name2"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1612279151891,
        "user": "email1",
        "ipAddress": "Ip1",
        "resourceType": "Login",
        "resourceName": "name1"
    }
]
```

**And I want the output from my JSON string to look like this**

```
[   {
        "timestamp": 1612279167153,
        "user": "email2",
        "ipAddress": "Ip2",
        "resourceType": "Login",
        "resourceName": "name2"
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1612279151891,
        "user": "email1",
        "ipAddress": "Ip1",
        "resourceType": "Login",
        "resourceName": "name1"
    }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: You said one record, but in the output section you are showing one record . Why ?

Comment: Jason is an Elixir library, but this question is tagged Python. Please [edit] your question clarify what you are trying to do, what specific problem you have, and which language you (intend to) use.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think he tried to tag JSON and by mistake tagged Jason. What do you think?

Comment: @PranbirSarkar I think they should [edit] their question. Especially since this is *not* JSON – it could be Python literals or something else – answering is guesswork otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First, the JSON string you mentioned is not a valid json because of one "," at the end `" }, ]`  and one more "," at `Name1", }`.

Assuming that you have corrected the JSON string. Now let's see the solution. But you have not properly mentioned how many latest records you want. Hence change the mentioned line in the below code accordingly.

```
import json

inp = '''[ { "timestamp": 1612283061106, "user": "email1", "ipAddress": "IP1", "resourceType": "Login", "resourceName": "Name1" }, 
{ "timestamp": 1612282839939, "user": "email1", "ipAddress": "Ip3", "resourceType": "Login", "resourceName": "name1" }, 
{ "timestamp": 1612279167153, "user": "email2", "ipAddress": "Ip2", "resourceType": "Login", "resourceName": "name2" }, 
{ "timestamp": 1612279151891, "user": "email1", "ipAddress": "Ip1", "resourceType": "Login", "resourceName": "name1" } ]'''

inp_dict = json.loads(inp)

inp_dict.sort(key= lambda x: x['timestamp'])

output = inp_dict[0:2] # <---- Change 2 to the number of latest records you want.

print(json.dumps(output))
```

Output :

```
[{"resourceName": "name1", "user": "email1", "resourceType": "Login", "ipAddress": "Ip1", "timestamp": 1612279151891}, {"resourceName": "name2
", "user": "email2", "resourceType": "Login", "ipAddress": "Ip2", "timestamp": 1612279167153}]
```

Comment: the file contain more than 4  records  and more than 2 resource name

Comment: @Moh'dHamtini You are only checking the timestamp, right? It could be 4 or 40 or 400. The same code will work, just need to change the value in the variable named `inp` .